# RDLC issue with mutiple datasets Winform project in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm building a report in report viewer. With a single dataset, it works great but I need to include in this same report, mutiple datasets. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong please (with some code if possible). I found a whole bunch of info on this issue but everything is not in the same programming language. I'm using C#. In the .RDLC, I have one datasource created and 2 datasets (DataSet and DataSet1). Here is my current code:

```
private void LoadReport()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("packing_slips", con);
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("client_info", con);

            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@project", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = project_id_box.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@project", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = project_id_box.Text;
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            adp1.Fill(ds1);

            reportViewer1.Reset();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
            reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];
            reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet";

            ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource();
            reportDataSource1.Value = ds1.Tables[0];
            reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1";

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "project_report.rdlc";

            this.packing_slipsTableAdapter.Fill(this.shopmanagerDataSet.packing_slips);
            this.projectsTableAdapter.Fill(this.shopmanagerDataSet.projects);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any compile errors when compiling but the report is blank. I'm retreiving the data from a MySQL db with stored procedures. When debugging i'm seeing that ds and ds1 are getting populated correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When adding mutiple datasets to a RDLC, you need to specify from what dataset the information is coming from in the textbox properties. EG:

> =First(Fields!project_number.Value, "DataSet")

That fixed it for me. The code above is good for anyone else having this issue.